# Random values combined with assignment/combinator operator

Tags: java, random, assignment-operator

Does the following code sample create two random values, or does it re-use the first one?

```
Random r = new Random();
int[] a = new int[10];

a[r.nextInt(10)] += 1;

// Equals this, creating two random values:
a[r.nextInt(10)] = a[r.nextInt(10)] + 1;

// Or this, using 6 as the result of the first random operation
a[6] = 6 + 1;
```

Edit: while we're at it, does this operator (and others like `-=`, `/=`, etc) have a name?

Comment: While I didn't downvote, understanding what `+=` is would be enough to answer the question, and this is in the JLS. Testing is easy, although you'd need to iterate to ensure you're past the probability of repeated random values. You wouldn't need to iterate for long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `a[r.nextInt(10)] += 1;` there is only one random number generated. So if this random number happens to be `6` this is equivalent to `a[6] = a[6] + 1;` (but slightly more efficient).

> does this operator (and others like -=, /=, etc) have a name?

They are called shortcut assignment operators.